# NativeScript - How can I resolve this crash when using 'BottomNavigation' in an iOS build?

Tags: ios, nativescript, bottomnavigationview

Help needed! Please.

I have written a basic NativeScript (v7.2.1) application and I'm using the 'BottomNavigation' component. [Doc](https://v6.docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/bottom-navigation)

This works perfectly fine when running the NativeScript preview app to test on an iOS device however when I build the app and launch it on an iOS device the app crashes due to the below exception which says "Module 'BottomNavigation' not found for element 'BottomNavigation'."

I'm not sure what to do to resolve this as 'BottomNavigation' component is part of the core components.

Any help and info on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Uncaught Error: Building UI from XML. @app-root.xml:1:1 > Building UI from XML. @home/main-page.xml:3:5 > Building UI from XML. @home/home-page.xml:23:5 > Module 'BottomNavigation' not found for element 'BottomNavigation'. > instanceType is not a constructor
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this which was to downgrade the version number for NativeScript Core module. I had updated to the latest version which no longer includes BottomNavigation.

I downgraded to v7.2.1 and it worked fine.

"@nativescript/core": "^7.2.1"